# How does an iOS developer get his app/game on the AppStores main page?

Tags: game-design, ios, appstore

I was looking at the front page of the AppStore, and they display a new game and a new app every day. I was just curious, how does an iPhone developer get their game or app onto that front page? Does Apple choose what goes on there? Or do you pay money?

I was just curious, I don't develop games for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, Apple makes their choices as to what goes in various featured sections at their discretion. If you have a good partnership with Apple, you may be able to guide their eye to your project, but in the end, it’s entirely up to them, and is not monetarily motivated (except that Apple gets paid when you buy apps and make in app purchases).

Comment: Apple actually doesn't get any royalties from apps on the AppStore. To put your app on the AppStore you have to pay Apple 100$ a year to continue to use their products. But Apple doesn't gain any royalties from an actual purchase made one the AppStore. Aside from that, thanks for your insight.

Comment: They do. They get 30% of all sales. Source: I have released many apps on the App Store.

Comment: Really? I'm sorry, I helped a friend release his app onto the AppStore, I didn't know about that. My apologies I should have checked before jumping to a conclusion.